# json_encode возвращает объект вместо массива

Tags: php

Если я удаляю из массива с целочисленными индексами элемент, а затем применяю к нему функцию `json_encode` то получаю строку с JavaScript объектом вместо строки с массивом.

Вот пример кода:

```
$a = [1, 2, 3];
unset($a[0]);
echo(json_encode($a)); // {"1":2,"2":3}
```

Как получить на выходе строку с массивом?

В случае с примером выше, вывод должен быть вот таким:

```
[2,3]
```

Comment: Строго говоря, `json_encode` возвращает строку.

Comment: @vp_arth, разумеется, речь именно о строках

Comment: Хотя, вы правы, заголовок менять не стоит, так релевантнее)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Почему это происходит:**

При удалении элемента (не являющегося последним) в ключах массива появляется "дырка". При этом, функция [`json_encode`](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.json-encode.php) обрабатывает такой массив не как массив с целочисленными ключами, а как ассоциативный массив (которому ставится в соответствие объект JavaScript).

**Что делать:**

Для того, чтобы получить на выходе массив, нужно нормализовать его ключи, например с помощью функции [`array_values`](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.array-values.php):

```
$a = [1, 2, 3];
unset($a[0]);
$a = array_values($a);
echo(json_encode($a)); // [2,3]
```

Answer (score 1):

Дима, всё доступно объяснил, от себя только добавлю ещё 1 вариант удаления элемента из массива функцией [array_splice](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.array-splice.php).

> Удаляет часть массива и заменяет её чем-нибудь ещё

```
$a = [1, 2, 3];
array_splice($a , 0, 1);
echo(json_encode($a));
```